# Emacs - how to install and use dired+?

Tags: emacs, windows-7, dired

I'm using GNU Emacs 24.2.1 on Windows 7. 
I want to use the `dired+` features, but I am not able to load them appropriately.

The file dired+.el exists in my lisp path.

I added the line `(require 'dired+)` in my configuration file which is loaded during Emacs' startup.

But when I type `C-x d`, it seems to me that the "normal" dired is loaded, not dired+.

- How can I tell if I'm using dired+ or dired?
  it looks like that:
  [image]
- I *can* use commands that start with `diredp-` however, so it seems that dired+ is somehow loaded, but e. g. I do not see the additional commands in the context menu available by right-clicking with the mouse which should allow me to open a directory in Windows explorer e. g. (like described here in the dired+ wiki: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus )

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the comments in the header of dired+.el, dired+ does not augment the usual dired-mode display, instead you have to use dired+ specific entry points to enter the dired+ buffer.

```lisp
;;  Additional suggested key bindings:
;;
;; (define-key ctl-x-map   "d" 'diredp-dired-files)
;; (define-key ctl-x-4-map "d" 'diredp-dired-files-other-window)
```

So you are overriding the usual `C-x d` key binding (`dired`) with one for `diredp-dired-files`.